# When someone's behavor is admirable or... in your view

Tags: word-request

Imagine someone helps a beggar and you see their action / behavior and like it and want to give a compliment to them. 
OR 
someone says you some bad words in a situation and you instead give him a smile and ask him to keep calm without saying even a single bad word.
I would be thankful if someone could tell me if in AE it is possible to say:

> - His / her behavior was really **admirable**.

I'm asking this question because many dictionaries confirm that it is possible, but as far as I know in AE people use this adjective to describe a very serious situation like self-devotion or something like that. E.g. a pilot who saves 300 passengers lives by doing something very risky.
If my taking is right, then I would be thankful if you could let me know how an AE native speaker would say the same thing in natural language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your understanding of

> admirable
>   His / her behavior was really **admirable**.

Anything that can or should be admired can be called ***admirable***.
It is how a native might phrase it.

Another adjective which could be used in the same context is

> exemplary
>   The courage the firefighters showed in fighting the fire was **exemplary**.

when an action should be held up as an example or model for people's behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter, but I did not follow you  well! Did you mean using admirable / exemplary in such contexts like mine would not be considered as an exaggeration?

Comment: Meanwhile, I would be thankful if you could let me know the opposite of these two adjectives if these two are acceptable in this sense. E.g. when someone's behavior is not admirable / exemplary in a situation. The only adjective I found was "distasteful". Could you please give me some more information in this respect too? :)

Comment: **Despicable** (deserving hatred and contempt) and **abhorrent** (inspiring disgust and loathing; repugnant) are two that come to mind.

Comment: Peter, what about "distasteful"?

Comment: I would say that *something* that is "distasteful" is not necessarily "admirable", but your question seems to ask about the *reaction* to *something* and not the quality (distasteful) of the *something*. *Something* which is distasteful may be exemplary or admirable in its distastefulness (this can often happen in the art world).